# linkedin iframe embed blocked samesite

Tags: codeigniter, iframe, http-headers, linkedin-api, content-security-policy

Since version 84 of chrome, linkedin content iframes are totally blocked and chrome displays the following message ( with a grey bloc ):

A cookie associated with a cross-site resource at http://google.com/ was set without the `SameSite` attribute. It has been blocked, as Chrome now only delivers cookies with cross-site requests if they are set with `SameSite=None` and `Secure`.

I did a lot of research but I still can't find how I can set up my Content-Security-Policy and my headers exactly so that they accept iframes feeds from linkedin.

I tested an ini_set :

```
ini_set('session.cookie_samesite', 'None');
ini_set('session.cookie_secure', TRUE);
```

I tried to modify my headers too ( i actually use CI 3.14 ) :

```
$this->output->set_header("Content-Security-Policy", "default-src 'self' *.linkedin.com");
```

But nothing work at all... Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: It is the Linkedin page/site which has to update their cookie policy, i.e set their SameSite cookie header to None., so that you could embed the iframe. Please add more details on what exactly Linkedin cookie policy is for that iframe.

Comment: Had the same problem, but it was blocked by them and now its fixed.